# How to set the display name for an Google Apps email alias?

Tags: gmail, alias

To indicate the message recipient, an email address may have an associated **display name** for the recipient, which is followed by the address specification surrounded by angled brackets, e.g.:

```
John Smith <john.smith@example.org>
```

In the example above the display name is `John Smith`.

Setting the display name for a normal Gmail account is easy, but how to set the display name for a Google Apps email alias?

I see no way to configure it when creating an alias:

[image: Google Apps email alias]

Answer (score 1):

After you create your alias through Admin Console then you have to set it up as a sender in your Gmail settings.

Gmail Mailbox > Gear icon > Settings > Accounts > Send Mail as : Add another email address that you own

You put the **display name** you want, you enter the alias you created through Admin Console (someuser@gmail.com), you leave checked the "Treat as an alias" box and you are ready to go.